# Use object directly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an object that receives a selector as an argument, which has one method named **`stylise`**, which is used to make alterations to the CSS of the HTML element(s) selected.

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function get(selector) {
    var
        self = {},
        elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    
    this.stylise = function(object) {
        Object.keys(object).forEach(function(propertyName) {
            for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
                elements[index].style[propertyName] = object[propertyName];
            };
        });
    };
    
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(self, this.prototype);
};
```

```html
<!----- HTML -----> 
<input id = "text" type = "text" style = "padding: .5em .7em;"/>
```

If the line **`return Object.setPrototypeOf(self, this.prototype);`** is skipped the above code will work as expected by calling it like:

```
var a = new get("#text");
a.stylise({
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    borderRadius: "5px"
});
```

However, I want the above to work by calling it like:

```
get("#text").stylise({
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    borderRadius: "5px"
});
```

I tried to achieve that by using **`Object.setPrototypeOf(self, this.prototype)`**, but to no avail as I got the following error in the console: **`Object doesn't support property or method 'stylise'`**.

What part of my code is causing this and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `setPrototypeOf` for that (there are very, very few situations where it's what you would reach for), just have `get` return the object you've created and assigned to `self` and assign to `self.stylise` rather than `this.stylise`:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function get(selector) {
    var
        self = {},
        elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    
    self.stylise = function(object) {
        Object.keys(object).forEach(function(propertyName) {
            for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
                elements[index].style[propertyName] = object[propertyName];
            };
        });
    };
    
    return self;
}
get("#text").stylise({
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    borderRadius: "5px"
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML -----> 
<input id = "text" type = "text" style = "padding: .5em .7em;"/>
```

In fact, you can create `stylise` within the object initializer. You can also use `forEach` on `elements`:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function get(selector) {
  var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));

  return {
    stylise: function(object) {
      Object.keys(object).forEach(function(propertyName) {
        elements.forEach(function(element) {
          element.style[propertyName] = object[propertyName];
        });
      });
    }
  };
}
get("#text").stylise({
  backgroundColor: "yellow",
  borderRadius: "5px"
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input id="text" type="text" style="padding: .5em .7em;" />
```

---

You've said elsewhere that you want to define `stylise` outside the constructor (and that putting `elements` on the object was fine). If so, you do that by using `Object.create` to create an object backed by a specific prototype object (in our case, `get.prototype`); this does what `new` does when it creates objects before calling the constructor, but you've said you don't want to use `new`.

Note that this example first creates two objects via `get`, then calls `stylise` on them; the various attempts you posted trying to do this would fail in that scenario:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */

// The builder function
function get(selector) {
  // Create a new object we'll return, backed by `get.prototype`
  var obj = Object.create(get.prototype);
  
  // Put the elements matching the selector on it
  obj.elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  
  // Return it
  return obj;
}

// Add `stylise` to the prototype `get` assigns objects
get.prototype.stylise = function(object) {
  // Get our elements, so we don't have to worry about `this` in the callbacks below
  var elements = this.elements;
  
  // Style them
  Object.keys(object).forEach(function(propertyName) {
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style[propertyName] = object[propertyName];
    });
  });
};

// Using it
var t1 = get("#text1");
var t2 = get("#text2");
t1.stylise({
  backgroundColor: "yellow",
  borderRadius: "5px"
});
t2.stylise({
  backgroundColor: "green",
  borderRadius: "10px"
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input id="text1" type="text" style="padding: .5em .7em;" />
<input id="text2" type="text" style="padding: .5em .7em;" />
```

---

Side note: Function declarations don't need `;` after them (although putting one there is harmless). `;` is for terminating statements. Declarations aren't statements.

Comment: Thanks @T.J., your answer works great. It's very thorough and provides some nice alternatives to solving my issue.